# Custom shaped buttons in Android - Am I doing it right?

Tags: android, imageview, shapes

I'm trying to implement four custom shaped buttons like you can see in the following picture:

[image]

What I did so far: I took 4 different pictures - each with only one color visible (see above). The other part of the image is transparent. This has the result, that I have four pictures with the same size.

Now I used a relative-layout where all my 4 pictures are added into imageviews on the same position. Because of the transparency, I can see the desired picture.

For my ImageViews I've implemented onTouchListener with the following content:

```
private class ImageOnTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    private int categoryId;

    public ImageOnTouchListener(int categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();
        boolean isInsideBitmap = x < bmp.getWidth() && y < bmp.getHeight() && x >= 0 && y >= 0;
        boolean isActionUp = event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP;
        if (isInsideBitmap) {
            int color = bmp.getPixel(x, y);
            bmp.recycle();
            if (color == Color.TRANSPARENT){
                return false;
            }
            else {
                if (isActionUp) {
                    buttonClick();
                }
            }
        }else{
            bmp.recycle();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

This approach works but it consumes a lot of memory as I'm always creating a bitmap when I move my finger. I'm not quite sure if this is the best way to implement this. Is there anything I can do different which might result in a more efficient way?

Comment: Did you try to compose a PNG where all the 4 images are patched together into a single one? It should save a lot of memory at the very least

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I'm not quite sure what you mean with compose a png. Do you have any source for me where I can get some information about this?

Comment: Yeah I don't see the need for 4 different PNGs, just use 1 like the left-most image and determine which quadrant you're in using the coordinates.

Comment: You mean I should only use one picture and determine in my onTouch which of the parts is clicked? I only posted a small snippet of my implementation. Each image has a focus and selected state as well. So I have to change the color of only one part of the picture if an event occurs.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. Although I'd say you should go with a custom drawable implementation, look into ArcShape http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/ArcShape.html

Comment: Composite PNG means using GIMP/Paint.Net to make a PNG of the actual 4 quadrants the exact way you want them on the device, like the first image you posted. You can also go with danmason's suggestion and achieve really good performance boosts as there would be no alpha for the GPU to calculate

Comment: My images are 9patch images, size is less than 5kb. I don't think my problem is in this part but in the detection of the pressed button. I'm not quite sure if I should create a bitmap from the drawing cache inside of the onTouch-Method because this is a method with a huge memory consumption

Comment: @Frame91 Why do you not use four buttons with custom drawables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the fact that you can tell whether or not coordinates belong in a circle with the equation `x² + y² <= radius²` when the circle's center is (0, 0), I think the following should work.

```
public class ImageOnTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    // TODO  Adjust this value
    private static int QUADRANT_RADIUS = 100; // in pixels
    // TODO  Adjust this value
    private static int SPACE_BETWEEN_QUADRANTS = 5; // in pixels

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int relativeX = (int) (event.getX() - v.getX());
        int relativeY = (int) (event.getY() - v.getY());
        int center = QUADRANT_RADIUS + (SPACE_BETWEEN_QUADRANTS / 2);

        boolean isInsideCircle = Math.pow(relativeX - center, 2) + Math.pow(relativeY - center, 2) <= Math.pow(center, 2);

        boolean isInsideBottomLeftQuadrant = isInsideCircle &&
                relativeX <= QUADRANT_RADIUS &&
                relativeY >= QUADRANT_RADIUS + SPACE_BETWEEN_QUADRANTS;
        boolean isInsideBottomRightQuadrant = isInsideCircle &&
                relativeX >= QUADRANT_RADIUS + SPACE_BETWEEN_QUADRANTS &&
                relativeY >= QUADRANT_RADIUS + SPACE_BETWEEN_QUADRANTS;
        boolean isInsideTopLeftQuadrant = isInsideCircle &&
                relativeX <= QUADRANT_RADIUS &&
                relativeY <= QUADRANT_RADIUS;
        boolean isInsideTopRightQuadrant = isInsideCircle &&
                relativeX >= QUADRANT_RADIUS + SPACE_BETWEEN_QUADRANTS &&
                relativeY <= QUADRANT_RADIUS;

        boolean isActionUp = event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP;

        if (isActionUp) {
            if (isInsideBottomLeftQuadrant) {
                // Handle bottom left quadrant click
                buttonClick();
                return true;
            } else if (isInsideBottomRightQuadrant) {
                // Handle bottom right quadrant click
            } // etc.
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

You'll need to adjust the `QUADRANT_RADIUS` and `SPACE_BETWEEN_QUADRANTS` values, and then either handle all touch events from a single view (like my snippet does) or have a slightly different touch listener per image.